# Sybase sql - get records in 3 queries

Tags: sql, pagination, sybase

I have a table that has about 90000 records.
I couldn't get all records in single query due to big size.
I could split the query into 2.
 But not 3.
Can you please tell me the query to get
1. query for first 30000 records
2. query for second 30000 records
3. query to get third 30000 records.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Why can't you get all the rows in a single query?

Comment: The resultset size is more than 1 GB.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to extract all the records to a file or for some sort of display?  What queries have you tried already that aren't giving you the results  you expect?  Please give more information when asking a question, as it will help people point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also Sybase was a company, and not a database, so you should specify which Sybase product and version (ASE, IQ, SQL Anywhere?) you are using, since the syntax varies between products.